# SQl rows to columns conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have a table ClassAttendance and I'm using MSSQL 2005

```
studentID    attendanceDate    status
-------------------------------------
*1004          2010-03-17        0
 1005          2010-03-17        1
 1006          2010-03-17        0
 1007          2010-03-17        0
*1004          2010-03-19        0
 1005          2010-03-19        1
 1006          2010-03-19        0
 1007          2010-03-19        0
*1004          2010-03-20        1
```

as you can see studentID is a foreign Key for a table called StudentData and attendedDate has an unknown number of rows.

Can i get the output like below by using a query? I need the dates in one month to be columns and the value of the date columns will be values in the status column. The number of date records per studentID is the same its the number of dates in the attendanceDate filed that is unknown.

```
studentID   2010-03-17   2010-03-19   2010-03-20
------------------------------------------------    
1004            0            0            1
```

etc.
This is for a creating a report so I need to do it in a query. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PIVOT. Take a look at [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1019).

Comment: Yes that would work but the thing is you have to know the field values before hand to use that don't you?? The problem here is there is no telling how many dates per month will be inserted in the table and no idea about the dates... And how can I get the date as the column name? The example doesn't show that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something using the [SQL 2005 PIVOT clause](https://web.archive.org/web/20191230182030/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/lorint/archive/2006/08/04/87166.aspx)? (see also: [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16))

Comment: Yes that would work but the thing is you have to know the field values before hand to use that don't you?? The problem here is there is no telling how many dates per month will be inserted in the table and no idea about the dates...

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Matrix control](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/advanced-matrix-reporting-techniques/) in the report (or CrossTab in an Access report, or equivalent in your client tool)

SQL is a fixed column definition/contract language and you don't know how may columns you'll have. It's not really a SQL problem but a presentation problem.

Unless you use dynamic SQL PIVOT... not the SQL Server 2005+ PIVOT command which again is fixed, known columns

Comment: Thanx dude but I want it for a report and I'd prefer if I can just get the results using a query!

Comment: A report implies presentation. You can crosstab in Excel if you wanted. But SQL aint the place to do it.