# convert rows in colums in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I’ve been looking for a way to show  one rows in multiple colums, one cell. The content of it separated by comma’s.

For example, in stead of:

```
ProjectID      Label
————           ——–
1200           label1
1200           label2
1200           label3
```

I would like the result of my query to look like this:

```
ProjectID                      1        2        3
————                   ——– 
1200                          label1  label2, label3
```

thanks in advance

Comment: have to create seperated columns not in commas

Comment: There are many articles about this like;

[Article 1](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/switching-rows-and-columns-in-sql/),

[Article 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482398/sql-rows-to-columns-conversion),

[Google Search Result](http://www.google.com.tr/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=sql+rows+to+columns&oq=sql+rows+&gs_l=hp.3.0.0j0i30l3.885.6537.0.8099.19.15.2.2.2.0.232.2248.0j14j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.Yizvx9UVIWM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.ZWU&fp=daea5479fc9f2712&biw=1920&bih=994)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more challenging than just the use of `pivot`, but only a little.  The problem is that you don't have a column to specify *where* the labels go, so you have to add it.

Here is a solution using aggregation:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by ProjectId order by label) as seqnum
      from t
)
select ProjectId,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then label end) as [1],
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then label end) as [2],
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then label end) as [3]
from t
group by ProjectId;
```

Here is the solution using pivot:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by ProjectId order by label) as seqnum
      from t
)
select ProjectId, [1], [2], [3]
from t
pivot (max(label) for seqnum in ([1], [2], [3])
      ) as pvt
```